# Linking two strings from list to use for GraphPlot using functions

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I was wondering if anyone has an idea how to use Cases or DeleteCases or something similar to get next result:

I have a list of strigs: `l={"KA Name", "KB Name2", "KA Other", "Something", "KB S2"}`

I want to connect the strings with same two letters before the name, result should be `l2={ "KA Name" -> "KA Other", "KB Name2" -> "KB S2"}` because I need to plot this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l = {"KA Name", "KB Name2", "KA Other", "Something", "KB S2"};

rg = RelationGraph[UnsameQ[##] && SameQ[StringTake[#, 2], StringTake[#2, 2]] &, l]
```

[image]

```
Rule @@@ EdgeList[rg]
```

> ```
> {"KA Name" -> "KA Other", "KB Name2" -> "KB S2"}
> ```

Alternatively, use `GroupBy` and `Subsets` to get the edge list directly:

```
Join @@ Values @ GroupBy[l, StringTake[#, 2] &, Rule @@@ Subsets[#, {2}] &]
```

> ```
>  {"KA Name" -> "KA Other", "KB Name2" -> "KB S2"}
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @me995, my pleasure. Welcaome to mma.se. And thank you for the accept.